# Show incorrect html on page that doesn't influence the rest of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml, w3c

I have got some detail content pages on my site where I don't have the complete control over the html content that is displayed in a certain div. Now when the content of the external resource contains invalid html, like having no ending  my navigation in the right-bar is also italic. I don't want to use iframes, like ebay, and there is probably other ways to fix this. Hope on an answer.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="page">
<div id="content">[content of external resource]</div>
<div id="right-bar">[My navigation]</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

A simplified structure of my page is above.

Comment: How are you inserting this external source? AJAX? Server side generated page?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to tell people to use Tables when they aren't necessary, but in this case, I feel that it could solve your problem.

The issue that you are facing is one of the browsers well-formed html check, so, you could have some browsers that work as you hope, and others that work the way that bothers you, as each rendering engine is going to perform it's own well-formed html check flavor.

If you wrap it inside a td, then I don't think that it will be able to bleed styling the way that you are seeing. Just a thought. The reason that a td container is going to help more than the div container that you are currently using is the following: Since you are wrapping their stuff in a div, and they are most likely wrapping their own stuff in divs, the browser doesn't know where the mistake is at. It doesn't know where the missing div tag should be inserted. So essentially, div in div in div creates problems for the well-formed html check, as it is not sure which of the tag you forgot. However, div in div in td, that is more distinct. If the td open and closes, then it knows that the missing tags belong to a smaller group of possible elements. In other words, you are making it easier on the well-formed check to do it's job by wrapping it inside different tag types.

This makes sense to me. I hope that I have explained it ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no other way than using iframes. If you don't use an iframe to host the external content means that the external content will be included in the DOM structure of your page, so unless you parse all the external content code to check all the possible things that should affect your page (and this could be a madness), you will never be sure that your page will be safe from collateral effects coming from the external code.

And even using iframes, you should parse anyway the external content to look for script tags, to prevent any undesired javascript code been executing inside your page.

Comment: I agree with you and i don't want to go that way of checking everything.